# Set up cocos2d-x-3.6 with eclipse on linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I installed cocos2d-x-v3.6 and want to use it with an kubuntu repository version of eclipse (v3.8).

Although I added the path to cocos to the project's 'Path and Libraries > Includes' settings, I get a lot of errors of the sort:

- Method '...' could not be resolved.
- Function '...' could not be resolved.
- Type '...' could not be resolved.

This is already true for the example code, see pictures.

[image: Error example]

This seems to be the case for mostly functions/variables in cocos namespaces, because basic classes, like 'Scene' are recognized.

[image]

What do I have to change in my settings so that also the members for this third-party framework are recognized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

I started from scratch, installing cocos and all dependencies following [these instructions - including android setup](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Android_with_Terminal_Installation_and_Setup). (Before that, I followed  [the linux instructions](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Linux_Installation_and_Setup) and tried eclipse on that.)

I then used the cocos command line tool to build a new app skeleton, [as described here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Creating_A_New_Example_Project).

Afterwards, I **imported** the `proj.android` subfolder into eclipse as an android project, as is described [here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Android_with_Eclipse_Installation_and_Setup) for the `cpp-tests` example project shipped with cocos2d-x. (Importing libcocos2dx seemed not to be necessary at this point.)

All symbols, functions, methods where resolved by eclipse.
I had a look at the C++ `Path and Libraries > Includes` settings and there was a lot going on, many cocos subfolder are referenced.

However, autocompletion was still not working. I checked all checkboxes in  the preferences at `C++ or Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced` and this did the trick, see screenshots.

[image] [image]